# Is it wrong to use a singular "is" following multiple abstract nouns?

Tags: grammar

Does the  "is"  in the [quote](http://webuser.bus.umich.edu/spreitze/Pdfs/DevelopAdaptLeaders.pdf) below constitute a grammar error?

> We need leaders whose core purpose in life is to make a positive
>   difference in the lives of others, and who embody the courage,
>   empathy, integrity and drive that **is** necessary to tackle tough
>   challenges.

Comment: Depends on whether you regard courage/empathy/integrity/drive to be individual attributes or a collective attribute.  IOW, opinion-based.

Comment: @HotLicks Can you elaborate on that with more examples?

Comment: Well, "His strength and stamina is amazing", vs "His suit and coat are ugly".

Answer (score -1):

Yes, that’s a grammatical error. The subject is clearly plural, since it’s four different things, and so should take a plural verb.

Comment: Do educated native English speakers also make such errors? I see the authors of the article are in some relatively important management positions so presumably educated natives.

Comment: @zell Yes, such mistakes are fairly common in complex sentences. In this case I suspect the author lost track of the syntax and mistakenly referred back to “the primary purpose” instead of “courage, empathy, integrity and drive”.